# jQuery Date Picker hides when pressing Next/Previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker calendar. 
When I press next button the calendar popup hides. 
Due to this error I cannot select next month date.

Here is my code

```
$( "#moviedate" ).datepicker({
   showOtherMonths: true,
   selectOtherMonths: true,
   changeMonth: true,
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2114/ Working fine with your code

Comment: Use firebug and see in browser.Post error.Remove `,` from `changeMonth: true,`.

Comment: What about making fiddle and reproducing your issue. Problem is anywhere else in your code.

Comment: I checked in firebug & found that when I press next button then it is applying a style property - 'display:none' to ui-datepicker div. So once it applied then datepicker popup get hides.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2n3nnts/

If you are using another JavaScript library alongside jQuery. Your code should be in between the noConflict area:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
  (function( $ ) {
      $( "#moviedate" ).datepicker({
         showOtherMonths: true,
         selectOtherMonths: true,
         changeMonth: true,
       });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have tried above code also but still same issue. When press Next button the calendar popup hides.

Comment: If you are using another JavaScript library alongside jQuery. Your code should be in between the noConflict area:
    jQuery.noConflict();
      (function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
          // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
        });
    })(jQuery);